# Sites where I can ask academia-industry transfer questions

Tags: discussion

I know that this question is not be related to this site, but I just want to know the names of the sites where I can ask questions about academia-industry transfer. Questions like "example of companies using differential geometry and machine learning" is not fit for this site, for example. So I'd appreciate the names of the sites where I can ask them. Thank you!

Comment: That being said, I see two issues with your concrete question: 1) It is actually not about academia, but about subjects treated in academia. As such, it is unrelated to this site, and rather related to sites dealing with the topics you mention. 2) An "example of companies" is rather unspecific, and you should probably specified the intended purpose of the question. For instance, is the purpose finding out whether any such companies exist anywhere on the world? Is that actually interesting for the community to know?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to ask, it may be appropriate on this site, [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), or not on any StackExchange site.

- If you are looking for information about specific companies, that will not be appropriate on either site:  "make me a list" questions are generally a poor fit for the SE format.
- If you are looking for information about *scientific* careers in industry, it is likely to be appropriate for this site (e.g. [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48029/22733))
- If you are looking for information about the non-scientific aspects of industry, then Workplace.SE is the place to go.

Comment: '"make me a list" questions are generally a poor fit for the SE format.' --> I think OP acknowledges this and is asking for alternatives to SE

Comment: @BCLC Well, I've answered the part that I know how to answer, about which types of academia-industry transfer questions are good for SE.  For the rest, I leave that to others, if they have any good suggestions.